# cat: ssh-rsa: No such file or directory to add Codeship SSH to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, codeship

I'm trying to add codeship SSH to aws `cat ssh-rsa [SSH_KEY] >> .ssh/authorized_keys` but I've encountered following error `cat: ssh-rsa: No such file or directory` regarding http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/19-setting-up-simple-wordpress-deployment-with-codeship-to-aws-ec2

Please let me know how to solve it. Because I'm now trying to deploy nodejs application to aws with codeship. Or is there anyway I can deploy nodejs application to aws with codeship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the public key for your Codeship project on the projects *General* settings page. You can then take this key and add it to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the EC2 instance(s) you want to deploy to.

See https://documentation.codeship.com/general/projects/project-ssh-key/ for the documentation article on this topic.

Comment: yap, I know. I've already found that SSH key and trying to add/append inside aws like that `cat ssh-rsa [SSH_KEY] >> .ssh/authorized_keys` then encountered `cat: ssh-rsa: No such file or directory` following error.

Comment: You should be able to open the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file with an editor (e.g. `nano`) and then just append the key (that you copied from the _General_ settings page).

Comment: Alternatively you could also copy the key and run the following command `echo "PASTE_COPIED_KEY" >> "${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys"`